# Does the School of Magic count as all colours, or do you choose one colour when it's played and it is that colour permanently?

Tags: citadels

It states that it has the colour of your choice (for calculating income). Do you make that choice when the card is played and it becomes permanently yellow for example, or can you change it each round?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you choose each round.

In my version of Citadels (Fantasy Flight, 2009) there isn't a card called 'Mage Tower'.  There is however a very similar card called 'School of Magic' which text states.

> For purposes of Income, the School is considered to be of the colour
>   of your choice.  If for you are the King this round, for example, the
>   school is considered to be a nobel (yellow) district.

To me that sounds like the card you are describing with extra text clarifying which sound like it may be missing from your edition?  Also if you had to decide when it was build there should be some way of marking that and the game does not come with tokens for doing so.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why I typed that! I've fixed the question. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Essentially the School of Magic always adds to your colour-based income.

Comment: Note that during endgame scoring "School of Magic" does NOT change color and is always purple, so it doesn't provide additional help to get bonus for all colors. Though there is another building "Ghost city" that does exactly that, if you have met its prerequisites.

Comment: @Deo There's also the Court of Miracles (? - "Hof der Wonderen" in dutch) that can also count for any desired color at the end of the game.

Comment: @steenbergh It is the card I'm talking about. Purple district for two. Apparently correct english name is "Haunted City" rather than "Ghost City". It is top left one here.
https://boardgamegeek.com/image/147403/citadels?size=original

Comment: @Deo Yes, it's the same card. I'm kind of surprised about the difference in naming. Then again, we call this game 'Machiavelli', not Citadels...

Comment: Now that we've played about 5 games at work, Machiavelli is definitely a better name for it. I wasn't sure if there were any methods to get income from two colours during the income phase and thus it would matter if the school of magic was a single colour of your choice, or acted as all colours. But it looks like there isn't a way to do that, so it's not a problem.